# How do i make a "!kick" command message for discord server?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm tryin' to make my own discord moderator bot!And i need help with ''!kick'' command , like if i want to kick someone i simply use !kick @user

Been starting with things like

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client;
```

and then

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is running.');
});

client.on('message', msg => {
```

and there should go my kick command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some code in the [discordjs documentation](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/docs/examples/moderation.md)

```
// Import the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Create an instance of a Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();

/**
 * The ready event is vital, it means that only _after_ this will your bot start reacting to information
 * received from Discord
 */
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  // Ignore messages that aren't from a guild
  if (!message.guild) return;

  // If the message content starts with "!kick"
  if (message.content.startsWith('!kick')) {
    // Assuming we mention someone in the message, this will return the user
    // Read more about mentions over at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageMentions
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // If we have a user mentioned
    if (user) {
      // Now we get the member from the user
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      // If the member is in the guild
      if (member) {
        /**
         * Kick the member
         * Make sure you run this on a member, not a user!
         * There are big differences between a user and a member
         */
        member
          .kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
          .then(() => {
            // We let the message author know we were able to kick the person
            message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // An error happened
            // This is generally due to the bot not being able to kick the member,
            // either due to missing permissions or role hierarchy
            message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
            // Log the error
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        // The mentioned user isn't in this guild
        message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
      // Otherwise, if no user was mentioned
    } else {
      message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
    }
  }
});

// Log our bot in using the token from https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/me
client.login('your token here');
```

The main code for this is `member.kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')`, but you are going to want to nest it inside of certain conditional statements that check if the member exists and if the person writing the command is an administrator.

Comment: Np, happy coding.

Comment: i have youtube and twitch , lol thx for sub anyway , i noticed i got 1 more sub